# Why does requests module load different content than my browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have the following Python code:

```
req=requests.get("https://pythonhow.com/example.html")
content=req.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
all=soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "cities"})
```

When I paste this URL into my browser, I get the expected markup structure:

```
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <h1 align="center"> Here are three big cities </h1>
    <div class="cities">
        <h2>London</h2>
        <p>London is the capital of England and it's been a British settlement since 2000 years ago. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cities">
        <h2>Paris</h2>
        <p>Paris is the capital city of France. It was declared capital since 508.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cities">
        <h2>Tokyo</h2>
        <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan and one of the most populated cities in the world.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Yet when I examine the `requests.get` content, I have the following HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Not Acceptable!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Not Acceptable!</h1>
    <p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p>
</body>
```

Why does `requests` fetch different content than my browser? I suspect it has something to do with some request header, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is "Pardon our Interruption. something about your browser made us think you were a bot". Implies scraping ain't permitted and they have anti-scraping bots on their webpages.You need to add `headers`. You can try it:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0 '}
req=requests.get("https://pythonhow.com/example.html", headers=headers)
content=req.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
all=soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "cities"})
```

Answer (score 1):

it's all about the `headers` where the website validate your request against robots.

As you can see that within your request, `Mod_Security` web application firewall (WAF) blocked it. So you can just add the header and send the `GET` request. also you should be always checking the first request to see what's going on by checking the response by printing `r` which is a variable of the request.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())


main("https://pythonhow.com/example.html")
```